# scipy long pause while solving

Tags: python, scipy, root

I use from scipy.optimize the root module. This shall solve my system of equations. It does so but if the system enlarges the solver breaks two times. First after roughly 5000th loop and then at 10141th loop. After about 1 minute waiting time it continues and solves the system correctly within the overall 12000 runs.
My ram is always under 50 percentage of usage. My fan does not make any effort to hyperventilate and I do not know why it breaks these two times while solving the equation.
 Has anybody a an answer and can help me to stop scipy making breaks?

Comment: You would need to split the task to a multiple threads in order to get better performance.

Comment: Can you give some example data that lets us replicate the behaviour? And some profiling data would certainly be useful.

Comment: The example code is on github, I added you to collaborators. If you have time to look over it would be great! You can install the environment via <conda env create -f environment.yml> Run in folder examples/main.py